# Set value if sublist contain specific object with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have list of elements

```
List<Element>() list;
```

Class definition for `Element` looks like:

```
public class Element
{
   public bool IsActive {get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Element> SubElements { get; set; }
}
```

This list contains information

```
[{
 IsActive: false;
 Name: "A";
 SubElements:
      [{
        IsActive: false;
        Name: "B";
        SubElements: null;
      },
      {
        IsActive: false;
        Name: "C";
        SubElements: null;
      }]
},
{
 IsActive: false;
 Name: "D";
 SubElements:
      [{
        IsActive: false;
        Name: "E";
        SubElements: null;
      },
      {
        IsActive: false;
        Name: "F";
        SubElements: null;
      }]
}]
```

Question is **how to set `IsActive` to be true by `SubElement` name for first and second level of this structure**?

For example if I get "B", element with `Name = "B";` and its parent element shoud have `IsActive = true;`

I know how to do it with foreach loop, but is it possible to do it with Linq?

Comment: Why not simply loop over list to set IsActive to true, and then loop over their SubElements?

Comment: Okay, looks like I understood. To resolve this, you need to add `public Element Parent;` to `Element` class. Then you will be able to write LINQ, you're requesting.

Comment: @KamikyIT I can do this, but maybe with linq code could be more readable and optimal?

Comment: it's unreachable to do LINQ before you add parent reference, becouse, each element doesn't know about his hierarchy level(1st, 2nd - to set `IsActive = true `, else 3rd and more `IsActive = false `).

Comment: `list.foreach(li => li.IsActive = true; li.SubElements.foreach(ci => ci.IsActive = true;));`

Comment: Thanks, it is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ is not designed for modifying data but querying and transforming it. You could create a new copy of your list with modified `Element`s set:

```
public static List<Element> MakeActivatedList(List<Element> list, string activeName) {
    return list.Select(e => (e.Name == activeName || (e.SubElements != null && e.SubElements.Any(e1 => e1.Name == activeName))) ? new Element { IsActive = true, Name = e.Name, SubElements = (e.SubElements == null) ? null :  MakeActivatedList(e.SubElements, activeName) } : e).ToList();
}
```

But if you really want to set the values in the original list, you shouldn't use LINQ:

```
public static void SetActive(List<Element> list, string activeName) {
    foreach (var e in list) {
        if (e.Name == activeName || (e.SubElements != null && e.SubElements.Any(e1 => e1.Name == activeName)))
            e.IsActive = true;
        if (e.SubElements != null)
            SetActive(e.SubElements, activeName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying the `Element` class, I don't believe the behavior you described is possible using LINQ. You can however, use [`List<T>.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx), while utilizing LINQ's [`Enumerable.Any<TSource>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// for each Element e in list
list.ForEach(e =>
{
    // if any sub-Element e1 in element e has Name == "B"
    if (e.SubElements.Any(e1 => e1.Name == "B"))
    {
        // set Element e.IsActive = true
        e.IsActive = true;

        // for each sub-Element e1 in Element e, set e1.IsActive = true
        e.SubElements.ForEach(e1 => e1.IsActive = true);
    }
});
```